# Struct vs. array for multi-leveled data organization

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have some data that I need to organize. I should note that I'm new to C and C++.

I have a list of buildings, each with a quantity and array of resource rates associated with it. I need to loop through the list of buildings, multiply the quantity of each building by its resource differential, and sum them to arrive at a total resource differential.

**For instance:**

Ice Well: [-100 power, +50 water], n = 2

Solar Array: [+150 power], n = 2

Total: **[+100 power, +100 water]**

I'm confused as to how to organize my data. If I use a struct, it will be challenging to loop through, but an array will be confusing once the number of building types increases. At this point my best guess would be to couple an enum with an array to get the naming functionality of a struct with the looping functionality of an array. How should  I go about doing this?

Comment: A `struct` is a very different beast in C and C++. Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I would like to use C++ in this case. Edited the tags to reflect.

Comment: Since you're tracking objects that have multiple properties, I think your best bet is to use a struct. It won't be challenging to loop through, just create an array of structs. Then you can use a nested loop to sort through any arrays that you have within the struct.

Comment: How about a building class (or struct for that matter, which is like a class with only public methods and members in C++) and an std::vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to consider an approach like this: (live example: http://ideone.com/xvYFXp)

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Building {
  public:
    virtual int getPower() = 0;
    virtual int getWater() = 0;
    virtual ~Building() {}
};

class IceWell : public Building {
  public:
    virtual int getPower() {return -100;}
    virtual int getWater() {return 50;}
};

class SolarArray : public Building {
  public:
    virtual int getPower() { return 150; }
    virtual int getWater() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Building>> inventory;
    inventory.emplace_back(new IceWell);
    inventory.emplace_back(new SolarArray);
    inventory.emplace_back(new IceWell);
    inventory.emplace_back(new SolarArray);

    int total_power = 0;
    int total_water = 0;
    for (auto building : inventory)
    {
        total_power += building->getPower();
        total_water += building->getWater();
    }

    std::cout << "Total power: " << total_power << "\n";
    std::cout << "Total water: " << total_water << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The base class, `Building` defines the interface; essentially it lists the resources your buildings may produce or consume. The derived classes `IceWell` and `SolarArray` then implement that interface, defining the amount of a resource that one such building will source or sink. Finally, you have a vector containing some number of instances of the derived objects (held in shared pointers to handle the memory management for you!). You can loop over these and accumulate total values for each resource.

If the production / consumption values might change over time, you can hold these as (private) member variables of each derived class, and allow some mechanism to modify them. You could even have `getWater()` compute its value as a function of some measure of time, so the well might "dry up" as time progresses.

---

After posting my original answer (above), I found myself thinking about alternatives. I wrote the following in an attempt to explain some of the design options, their benefits and drawbacks, and how to go about reasoning about the design of a system like this. I hope it is helpful.

---

It is rare in C++ to find a "single correct solution". There are often several reasonable approaches, each of which will have its own set of relative merits and drawbacks.

When you're designing a program in C++, you will inevitably have to consider some of the possible solutions, and pick one based on its merits. Let's attempt to analyse the problem stated here...

You have some buildings, and these buildings have properties defining their resource usage. Some buildings are net producers, while other buildings are net consumers of a particular resource. This immediately identifies "resources" as an entity within the system. We might jump straight in and code up something that encapsulates our idea of net resource usage:

```
struct ResourceFootprint {
    int power;
    int water;
};
```

You can now represent different levels of resource consumption by instantiating that struct appropriately:

(Live example: http://ideone.com/ubJv8m)

```
int main()
{
    ResourceFootprint ice_well = {-100, +50};
    ResourceFootprint solar_array = {+150, 0};

    std::vector<ResourceFootprint> buildings;
    buildings.push_back(ice_well);
    buildings.push_back(ice_well);
    buildings.push_back(solar_array);
    buildings.push_back(solar_array);

    ResourceFootprint total = {0, 0};
    for (const ResourceFootprint& r : buildings)
    {
        total.power += r.power;
        total.water += r.water;
    }

    std::cout << "P: " << total.power << ", W: " << total.water << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This seems nice; we've packaged up the resources, they have handy names, and we can create new kinds of building just by providing the relevant values. This means we can have a building inventory, stored in a file, that might read something like:

```
IceWell,-100,50
SolarArray,150,0
HydroElectricPlant,150,150
```

All we have to do is read the file and create instances of ResourceFootprint. This seems like a reasonable solution; after all, the different kinds of resource are probably reasonably fixed, while the different kinds of building that produce and consume them could change often. You might want to add a Hospital, a GasStation, a Restaurant and a Farm.

But wait; Hospitals also consume Medicine, and produce MedicalWaste. Gas stations definitely need Oil, Restaurants will consume Food, as well as Water and Power, and Farms might produce Food, but they will require Oil, Power and Water to do so.

Now we're in a situation where the different kinds of resource have to change. The current mechanism still works out ok; we can add the resources to our struct:

```
struct ResourceFootprint {
    int power;
    int water;
    int oil;
    int food;
    int medicine;
    int medical_waste;
};
```

Things that didn't use the new resources before don't have to care (though the definition will probably need to zero out the extra resource fields), and things that use the new resources can be defined in terms of them:

```
    ResourceFootprint ice_well = {-100, +50, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    ResourceFootprint solar_array = {+150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    ResourceFootprint hospital = {-100, -50, 0, -50, -50, 50};
    ResourceFootprint gas_station = {-10, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0};
    ResourceFootprint restaurant = {-20, -20, 0, -100, 0, 0};
    ResourceFootprint farm = {-10, -30, -10, 200, 0, 0};
```

Better still, the existing code that computes total power and water usage will still work fine. We can just add the code for the other resources to it:

(Live example: http://ideone.com/rukqaz)

```
    ResourceFootprint total = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (const ResourceFootprint& r : buildings)
    {
        total.power += r.power;
        total.water += r.water;
        total.oil += r.oil;
        total.food += r.food;
        total.medicine += r.medicine;
        total.medical_waste += r.medical_waste;
    }
```

So far, so good. But what are the drawbacks of this approach?

Well, one obvious problem is that the resource footprint is just plain data. Sure, we can change the values, but we can't really do anything complicated, like have an IceWell dry up as time passes, or allow a SolarArray to produce different amounts of power depending on whether it is day or night. For this, we need the resource footprint to be computed in some way that might vary from one building type to another.

The original part of the answer explores one solution in which each building has its own type, with member functions that return the current consumption of the resource in question. As we just explored, we might need to extend our set of resources. We can do this by combining the two ideas; have a class for each building, and a struct to hold the resource usage. Each building class can then decide how to implement its resource usage.

The base class would look like this:

```
class Building {
    public:
        virtual ~Building() {}

        virtual ResourceFootprint currentResourceLevel() = 0;
};
```

We choose to return a ResourceFootprint by value (as opposed to returning a reference, or any other approach) because this allows us to trivially change the implementation. Discussion follows...

In the simplest case, a hydroelectric plant might just use a constant supply of water, and produce a constant supply of power. Here, it would keep a ResourceFootprint object as a (possibly const) member variable, and return a copy of it when asked for its resource consumption:

```
class HydroElectricPlant : public Building {
    public:
        HydroElectricPlant(const ResourceFootprint& r)
         : resources(r) {}

        virtual ResourceFootprint currentResourceLevel() { return resources; }

    private:
        const ResourceFootprint resources;
};
```

The IceWell might do something more complex:

```
class IceWell : public Building {
    public:
        IceWell(const ResourceFootprint& initial)
         : resources(initial) {}

        virtual ResourceFootprint currentResourceLevel() { return resources; }

        void useWater(int amount) { resources.water -= amount; }

    private:
        ResourceFootprint resources;

};
```

And the SolarArray might do:

```
class SolarArray : public Building {
    public:
        SolarArray(const ResourceFootprint& r)
         : day_resources(r), night_resources(r)
        {
            night_resources.power = 0;
        }

        virtual ResourceFootprint currentResourceLevel()
        {
            if (is_day())
            {
                return day_resources;
            }
            else
            {
                return night_resources;
            }
        }

    private:
        ResourceFootprint day_resources;
        ResourceFootprint night_resources;

};
```

The design now allows for:

- Adding new kinds of resource: The code above will continue to work when new fields are added to the struct (although you may need to make some changes to the initialisation of the struct to account for those new fields).
- Adding new kinds of building: You can write another class, inheriting from Building, and define its resource usage however you like.

What doesn't this cover?

- Dynamic creation of building types. The first solution, where a building is defined purely in terms of the values of the ResourceFootprint fields, allowed us to create new kinds of building just by makiung a new instance of the ResourceFootprint with appropriate values. This fits nicely with systems that allow you to make custom buildings, but doesn't provide much flexibility in how those values change over time.
- Dealing with new resource types without having to add more code. Each new resource type has a field in the struct, so you need to refer to it by name. You could just hold a std::vector whose elements are to be interpreted in a particular order (e.g. res[0] is water, res[1] is power) to achieve this goal, but you sacrifice code clarity to achieve that.
- Countless other possibilities that have not yet occurred to me!

There are, of course, other solutions, but I hope this has provided a little insight into the kind of thought process you're going to need to adopt when designing systems in C++. It's quite likely that you'll come up with a design you are happy with, get half way through your program, then realise that you have hit a wall where your design simply will not work. That's fine, it happens. Go back and do the design phase again, armed with the knowledge of where your first one went wrong.

Comment: This is fine for a naive OOP approach. But what if the building types and resources need to come from a text file? You've hardcoded the buildings. I only inherit when behaviour changes, not simple values. I would have a building class where the power, water, etc required are member variables.

Comment: You also miss a virtual destructor.

Comment: I did say "something like this". This answer was meant to provide some ideas, not to give the complete implementation of a production quality infrastructure catalogue!

Comment: This seems like the way to go. I would like to keep the resources stored in an array rather than as individual variables though--is this approach still possible?

Comment: @J.T Of course it is. I'd avoid an array, though. `std::vector` will be much easier to work with.

Comment: @NeilKirk another advantage of this approach is mentioned in the fnial paragraph of my answer - the behaviour could be changed on a per-structure basis, e.g. wells could "dry up", solar arrays could age, or produce different amounts of power at different times of day, etc. Furthermore, this is still reasonably extensible e.g. by providing a factory function to construct buildings of different types (and depending on implementation, having their properties read from a file or computed on demand). Having a class per building type doesn't constrain the number of building types that are possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is one feature about your problem that deserves a little bit more attention: You don't know yet what resources you will be using in the end. You don't even know whether or not you will want to add a resource or two in a future version 2.0, maybe allow your users to define their own resources, etc. So I think, you should think now about a more generic approach.

So what behavior do your buildings need? They need to be able to tell how they modify a resource of yet unknown name. They may or may not have to be able to tell which resources they modify, but the resource updating code should be able to take some list of resources with their associated state and calculate the resulting state from that.

Consequently, I would probably code something like this:

```
class Building {  //might be abstract
    public:
        virtual int getResourceDiff(std::string resource);  //might be pure virtual
};
```

and somewhere else

```
//the header
class SomeGameWorldClass {
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> resources;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Building> > buildings;
    public:
        void updateResources();
};

//the .cpp file
void SomeGameWorldClass::updateResources() {
    for(resourcePair : resources) {
        for(buildingPtr : buildings) {
            resourcePair.second += buildingPtr->getResourceDiff(resourcePair.first);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you the power to define new resource at will, and it gives you the freedom to calculate the resource updates in any way you want, depending on the type of the building. Heck, you might even define a `Building`-subclass that runs some user provided scenario-control code to do the calculation.

Of course, I have now just used the string/integer pairs of the hash map to store the name and the current amount of a resource. Most likely, this is not sufficient, you might need to add more behavior to your resources, like setting upper storage limits etc. So you'll very likely end up with another class to describe your resources:

```
class Resource {
    public:
        ...
    private:
        int curAmount, maxAmount;
        std::string name;
        ...
};
```

Comment: Great answer, and I like the way you lead naturally into defining `class Resource` as the conclusion of the design exercise. I'd have gone further down this road in my answer, but it was already getting quite long, so thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep this as simple as possible, using strings to indicate building type:

```
struct Building
{
    Building(std::string n, int p, int w) : name(n), power(p), water(w) {}
    std::string name;
    int power;
    int water;
};

int main()
{
    Building iceWell("Ice Well", -100, 50);
    Building solar("Solar Array", 150, 0);
    Building buildings[4] = { iceWell, iceWell, solar, solar };
    int totalPower = 0;
    int totalWater = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        totalPower += buildings[i].power;
        totalWater += buildings[i].water;
    }
}
```

This could be improved e.g. by using `std::vector` or whatever collection suits your problem instead of an array.

Comment: Is there anything gained by using classes instead of structs to define the building type?

Comment: @J.T A class and struct are the same thing. The only difference is a class defaults to private members.